# Add Header with image in word corrupts document

Tags: openxml

I have a Header with a table (1 row , 3 cells).In first cell there is a image and in 2nd and 3rd there are some text paragraphs

I append header to doc dynamically like this:

```
HeaderPart headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
    string rId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);
    HeaderReference headerRef = new HeaderReference();
    headerRef.Id = rId;
    headerRef.Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default;
    sectionProps.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
    sectionProps.Append(headerRef);
    headerPart.Header = HeaderCreator.GenerateHeader();
    headerPart.Header.Save();
```

In document there is a page with a group of shapes.
Everything works ok if I

1. Remove the page with shapes
2. Remove the logo from Header

Any suggestions?